# SSRS 2005 Report Automatically Rendering

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have created a number of SSRS 2005 reports, and provided a number of parameters for each. Each of the parameters have default values, and therefore the report automatically renders when someone visits the report through the SSRS web site.

What I'd like to do is have all the reports have their default values, but prevent the report from automatically rendering. I've looked online, and I haven't seen anything aside from people claiming that it cannot be done. I'm hoping to see some expert advice on this one for a method of preventing the reports from automatically rendering without having to develop a custom web interface.

Any thoughts?

Does anyone know if this behavior is different in SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, I had this exact same problem on one of my reports.  You must have at least one parameter that is not bound to a default value in order to achieve this effect, otherwise it is impossible as you suggested.

Proof:

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.reportingsvcs/browse_thread/thread/d9669fb82ecb18f0/87ed0eb0996d62bf?lnk=st&q=%22reporting+services%22+auto+load&rnum=4&hl=en&pli=1

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've come across is to have a single parameter that doesn't automatically have it's default value selected. The user only has to select one value and run the report. I prefer to make this the first parameter so it is consistant for each report, and anything beyond that is custom selections.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent Auto-Run for SSRS 2008 R2 using a visible Text parameter:

Create parameter with:  `DateType=Text, "Allow Blank"=True, "Allow Null"=False, "Visibility"=True, "Available Values"=None, "Default Value"=No default value.`